# String to Time(TimeSpan) error

Tags: c#, excel, timespan

```
public static TimeSpan Change(string span)
{
    TimeSpan interval;
    TimeSpan.TryParseExact(span, @"mm\.ss\.fff", null, out interval);
    return interval;
}


ws.Cells[3, 9] = "Average";
ws.Columns[7].ColumnWidth = 15.00;

for (int i = 0; i < nodeActualResultC.Count; i++)
{
    TimeSpan spanA = Change(nodeActualResultA[i].InnerText);
    TimeSpan spanB = Change(nodeActualResultB[i].InnerText);
    TimeSpan spanC = Change(nodeActualResultC[i].InnerText);

    TimeSpan result = (spanA + spanB + spanC);
    TimeSpan avg = new TimeSpan(result.Ticks / 3);

    args1[0] = avg;

    string A = Convert.ToString(i + 4);
    string B = "I" + A;
    Console.Write(B);

    Range aRange = ws.get_Range(B);
    aRange.NumberFormat = "mm:ss.000";

    aRange.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, aRange, args1);
}
```

This is a small part of my code. I am getting data from an XML node via Inner Text.

The part from ws.Cells inwards is in a method that gets time from string to `TimeSpan`. I am getting an **error** in the last line :

```
aRange.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, aRange, args1);
```

> ERROR: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Method's type signature is not Interop compatible

Please help!

Comment: Is this question about Excel Automation?

Comment: @MartinLiversage Hey! Yes. Any help from your end?

Comment: I'm not versed in the details of .NET to Excel interop but my guess is that you cannot pass a `TimeSpan` as the value of an Excel cell. You will have to decide how to represent the `TimeSpan` in Excel and then perform the appropriate conversion. Again guessing, you will have to convert the `TimeSpan` into a `DateTime` using the epoch of Excel dates (around year 1900). You then have to convert the `DateTime` into an _OLE Automation date_ (`DateTime.ToOADate`). Finally, you will have to change the format of the cell to display _Time_.

Comment: As the _OLE Automation date_ is a double representing days you should be able to convert a `TimeSpan` into an _OLE Automation date_ by dividing the total hours of the `TimeSpan` by 24: `var oaTime = timeSpan.TotalHous/24D` thus avoiding the _OLE Automation date_ epoch stuff.

Comment: @MattJohnson any help?